# Grails mail plugin works locally but fails on server

Tags: email, grails

I can't get the mail plugin for Grails to work properly on production server with the suggestions out there (such as checking for different versions of plugins)

With the same configuration it works in my local environment.

This is my Config.groovy

```
grails {

    // other configs

    mail {
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 465
    username = "xxx@gmail.com"
    password = "secret"
    props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    } ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the exception thrown:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:
    534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvYY
    534-5.7.14 rIXXHBxKKMt9ftNn9GuoppiRgCLMYf1-L3FM15F0yD0nZ_8AKpbuqjHm-6Jm7VBn8NluX9
    534-5.7.14 gJki2Giv7aWaflq3L1Vo7uZYIn_v7z1eLe51jbb2UawpOmwdzJLMDvbypH6WW3LyC80pUI
    534-5.7.14 3jm1omeGD_E-BecER_IGa7f4FsN1HMpRRIYRfPgxX_X0yZ276KrPvXR9t0eNqZ-XfF4Wp8
    534-5.7.14 WtEuhDF7ms_YZh25KdmFjuEwY8v0> Please log in via your web browser and
    534-5.7.14 then try again.
    534-5.7.14 Learn more at
    534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 q41sm10613096qkq.4 - gsmtp
```

I know what mailAuthenticationException means, but this works perfectly on local environment, so it's not user/pass data, and the email was configured to allow less secure access on Gmail account. So there should be something wrong in the code.

Im using mail:1.0.7 and grails 2.4.4.

P.D.: I will try on commons email of apache and see what happens...

Comment: First, [get rid of all those socket factory properties](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), you don't need them.  Then, tell us what "fails" means.  Are you getting an exception?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: my bad, edited, tried without the props that you pointed but the application   does not respond (even odder, no exception is being thrown)

Comment: Did you follow all the links in the error message?  Have you enabled less secure apps for your account?

Comment: Yes i did, as i mentioned before, i configured the account to allow less secure access applications.

Comment: If you've followed the accounts.google.com link in the error message (which you'll need to copy and paste into a single URL), and you've tried every one of the steps in the Gmail help page, and it's still not working, you're probably going to have to contact Google to ask them why they won't let you login to your account from your production machine.  Perhaps they've blacklisted that machine's IP address?  Or perhaps they think your account is being abused or being abusive?

Comment: So, this happened today, i changed the email on mail plugin configuration and it worked ... after being able to send emails on prod environment i tried to change the email to its original value, and surprisingly it worked just fine. I dont know why it worked as I ONLY changed the email for plugin configuration. Thanks to you all for your help!